# Fallen out of the world through the Void in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have fallen out of the void and I can't find the area where I built everything. I am on creative mode in a Super Flat World. Please tell me how I can find the place I built everything cause I cant find it! :(

Comment: @kotekzot can u please help me?!?!?!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie do you have any possible ideas that I could try?

Comment: Here's an idea! Try following the link in SevenSidedDie's comment and read answers there :)

Comment: where your build near spawn?? if so kill yourself and youl get to spawn

Comment: @Orc JMR That question is about finding the way back to spawn and pretty much all answers assume the player knows where their home is, even if that is just at spawn. Given that Nicole said he died and now can't find where he was I'd imagine he does not need to find his way back to spawn.

Comment: @colorfusion Well, if we read this in the most general way, such task - "How do I find one unknown place from another unknown place on an undistinguishable landscape?" - has no solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: @colorfushion Pretty much all, but *not* all. One answer is to use an external mapper to display the whole explored world. This will very quickly work for finding built-up stuff at an arbitrary location, not just spawn. (Also, rarely is the male pronoun assumption quite so obviously unwarranted as with "Nicole". The internet's biases are funny.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use external programs then it is possible to use generated and populated chunks to track the direction you went. Programs such as MCEdit will not generate any new chunks when looking around, so you can tell which ones have been generated by you in game.

First, you should install and open up [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) and then select your creative world from that. Make sure you close minecraft first.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IIOhz7z.png]

If your world does not show up on the list of worlds then click "Browse levels" and double click on your world's level.dat.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/YU7G4BQ.png]

MCEdit will place your camera in at wherever your player is on the world. You can use WASDQZ to move around the world and right click to toggle between mouse looking and mouse placing.

Zoom up, look down and get an overhead look at your world. Hopefully from the chunks that are generated you should be able to see the general direction you went and the buildings you made.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vNaSQCY.png]

Zoom back in on the buildings that you made.

[image]

Use the Move Spawn Point or Move Player tool to place your spawn point and/or player next to your buildings. If you use the move player tool make sure to select "Player" rather than your username.

[image]

Now when you log back into the world on minecraft you should be at your buildings, or have your spawnpoint set there.